# JPA-репозиторий возвращает пустой объект, если искать по типу Calendar

Tags: java, spring, jpa, h2

Есть сущность:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String IP;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Calendar visitTime;
...}
```

И есть запись в репозитории `List<Customer> findByVisitTime(Calendar calendar);`.

При попытке найти список объектов по данному методу, возвращается пустой объект.
Добавил аннотацию @Temporal, но результат не изменился.
Calendar - должен содержать время и дату.
Что можно добавить и куда, чтобы данные возвращались?.

Comment: а вы уверены что хранимое в базе и посылаемое вами значение совпадает? Там нет никаких временных зон например?

Comment: Действительно не совпадают.  При создании calendar без параметров, внутри задается текущее время. И отличается не только миллисекунды, но и параметр time, дни недели и неделя месяца... Похоже calendar не подойдет для хранения только даты и времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была из-за того, что при создании calendar через new без параметров задавалось текущее время, дата, дни недели,миллисикунды и т.д. Из-за этого поиск не находил ничего.
Получилось исправить обнулив вне иные данные для calendar до назначения параметров дата-время, как при создании базы из файла, так и в классе, откуда вызывается данный метод функцией ниже.

```
calendar.clear();
```